# Change the password Windows 7 has stored for a wireless network

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I have a new laptop which I used to connect to the guest network in our house. I typed in the wrong password at login and now I cannot type in the correct one.  How can I clear or change the password without having access to the router?

Comment: Adding a comment here to point out the ridiculousness of things. You can no longer do this very basic thing in Windows 10.

Answer (score 13):

### To modify a wireless network's profile...

1. Open the Control Panel and **click** `Network and Internet`.

   [image: Control Panel]
2. **Click** `Network and Sharing Center`.

   [image: Network and Internet]
3. **Click** `Manage wireless networks` on the left pane.

   [image: Network and Sharing Center]
4. **Right-click** on the wireless network and **click** `Properties`.

   [image: Manage Wireless Networks]
5. **Click** on the **Security** tab and edit the key in the `Network security key` field.

   [image: Properties]

> **Note:** If you don't want to retype the whole password, you can enable the `Show characters` option and edit from there.
>
> [image: show characters]

Comment: But it changes to previous one automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your system tray icon

[image: click on wireless network icon, right click the desired network, click on properties]

click on wireless network icon, right click the desired network, click on properties

[image: Click on show characters]

Click on show Characters and change the Network Security Key above it.

Comment: +1 for the more succinct answer!

Comment: @0xC0000022L it's succint but works only if you're connected to the network.

Comment: @Danyal that's a fair point. Indeed.