# Network security key field not visible when trying to update password

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, passwords

In the last step of the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/422678/147088), I don't see the text field for network security key:

[image]

How can I make it appear in order to update my password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have it set to "WPA2-Enterprise" instead of "WPA-Personal".

"Personal" uses a pre-shared key, whereas "Enterprise" depends on a centralized system for authentication.

Set it to "WPA2-Personal" and the box should become available.

Comment: Changing it to "WPA2-Personal" doesn't allow me to connect to the network.