# Windows 8 doesn't ask for Wifi credentials

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

UPC Wi-Free requires to enter a username and password, but when I try to connect, it doesn't ask me for it, but rather tries to connect right away - which of course fails.

I have read [Change the password Windows 7 has stored for a wireless network](https://superuser.com/questions/422677/change-the-password-windows-7-has-stored-for-a-wireless-network) , but don't have "Manage Wireless Networks" in the "Network and sharing Center". 
Also, the network I need to enter the credentials for ('UPC Wi-Free') isn't displayed in the list of registered networks, also not when entering "netsh wlan show profiles", so it doesn't (seem to) be saved on the computer, which also means I can't delete it from the list to get queried again.

Any idea what else I could do? Somehow it feels the network might still be saved 'somehow' (I set it up many months ago, but changed passwords since then), but in a hidden way, so login fails. Or whatever. x-)

Comment: You could try putting in the password by connecting manually, as if to a hidden network.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling your wireless driver with [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Reinstall-Wireless-Drivers) article. From my experience, that has always wiped the "Known Networks". Should fix any issues with your driver, too.

Summed up:

1. Find the device manager. (Windows 8+, right click start icon and select "Device Manager" and skip the rest of this step) In Windows 7 ("and probably Vista" direct quote from the article. You should be able to search it if you can't find it) this is done by entering the Start Menu, and then Right Clicking on the "Computer" item on the right side, then clicking "Properties". Using this panel, click Device Manager on the left side.
2. The device manager is a big long list of everything in your computer. If we are going to reinstall the driver, first we need to make the computer forget it had the device in question (a wireless card), that way it gets all shocked and amazed when one shows up and it re-installs the drivers. Now it's time to shock and amaze. Under "Network adapters" you should see a few different adapters, mainly one that has the words "Wireless" in its name.
3. Right click on the Wireless card, and click on the Uninstall button. It's going to ask you if you're sure, say you are (with clicking "OK") and watch it vanish from the list. (Don't click the "Delete the driver software for this device." just yet, that will be on try two if the first does not work)
4. Click the "Action" menu at the very top of the Device Manager, and select "Scan for hardware changes."
   Your computer just found this shiny new slightly used wireless card! Windows update jumps into action installing drivers, and hopefully it works out just as it was supposed to when you got it.

Just a side-note:
You may not be able to get the Wireless driver reinstalled. The good news is that your issue probably just identified itself as you were using the wrong driver, or a weird device. The bad news is you now either have to hunt down the driver yourself (where google will come in handy), or post to superuser.com with your system specs.

Comment: We frown in link only answers. As with your other answers, you really ought to edit this to be a self contained answer. Referencing is fine. We just don't want the [wisdom of the ages](https://xkcd.com/979/) to be lost.

Comment: Right. I will edit this like I did the other.